# Get comparable PostgreSQL version number

Tags: postgresql, versioning

I need to make sure that an available PostgreSQL version is not lower than required one. The version string could be requested as follows:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

It returns me something like:

> PostgreSQL 9.5.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Theoretically I could parse this string, but I am not sure that future versions of PostgreSQL server will keep this word order.

Does PostgreSQL have some predictable version report possibly split in major and minor version number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
show server_version_num; --returns 90602::text
show server_version; --returns 9.6.2::text
```

Answer (score 2):

https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/finding-postgresql-version/ says:

You can use that more easily within an SQL query like this

```
SELECT current_setting('server_version_num');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the PostreSql View `pg_settings` which is present at `pg_catalog`

```
select * from pg_settings where name like '%version%';
```

The query above will bring you two settings:

```
name                   other columns .....
server_version               .....
server_version_num           .....
```

For your specific case you will want the following configuration:

```
select name, setting, min_val, max_val 
  from pg_settings 
 where name = 'server_version_num';

name                   setting    min_val  max_val 
--------------------------------------------------
server_version_num     90503       90503    90503
```

From here you can work with `min_val` and `max_val`

This query is equivalent to the answer provided by @ŁukaszKamiński with some more detail (if you select all columns.)